# How to animate child from parent in the Animation view?

Tags: animation, unity

For some reason I can't change the value of the scale properties.

The scale properties belong to a child object, and I added them with "add Property".

[image]

What I'm trying to do is, adding an Animation to an empty parent object, which is going to animate a few of the child components for an menu opening animation. I need the animation on this parent object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible to animate multiple children objects via one animation component on the parent object. First, select your parent object in the object hierarchy. Then open up your animation window (if this is not already within view, it can be opened by clicking `Ctrl + 6`). Create a new animation clip and name it whatever you want. In your animation view shown below, you will see the button "Add Curve". When you click the "Add Curve" button, you will see all the components of the parent object as well as all of the children objects:

[image: Picture from Unity's own website]

Click on the triangle next to the child object's name and you should be able to choose which components of that child you want to animate.

Comment: It would be cool if that would work for me, but i don't have the "Add Curve" Button but only the "Add Property", though I think both should do the same. While I can add properties (or curves) like this I cannot modify the value that is visible. E.g. I can see that the scale is currently one but i cannot modify its value, nothing happens when I click on it. Could be a bug.

Comment: Okay, well I guess it was a bug then... I didn't try to restart Unity and guess what, that fixed it. Still wondering about the "Add Curve" ;)

Comment: Haha well that worked out well. I think the add curve might be present in later versions of unity. You appear to have an older one